# How can I get a set of permissions requested by an assembly?

Tags: .net, cas, .net-assembly, permissionset

I want to ask user to grant requested permissions or prevent assembly from loading.

Comment: You probably want to tag your question with ".net" to get a faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Standard User Analyzer tool to look for UAC issues:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766021(WS.10).aspx

If your application requires elevation, you can embed an application manifest specifying `requestedExecutionLevel` to prompt the user for permission:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: This question is not related to UAC. This is about [PermissionSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissionset.aspx)